# Integrating a differential 2 form over a surface

Tags: geometry, derivatives, differential-geometry

I am trying to integrate this 2 differential form :

$T\,$=$xyz\mathrm{d}y\wedge\mathrm{d}z+xy\mathrm{d}z\wedge\mathrm{d}x-y^2z\mathrm{d}x\wedge\mathrm{d}y$, where $\wedge$ is exterior product or wedge product.

The surface is $M :x^2+y^2=z^2$ for $z \in[0,2]$

My issue is I get a zero value for the integral : $\int_MT$ and i am not sure if its just my wrong parametrization or computation or if actually it is correct.

so I use the following I believe intuitive cylindrical parametrization :

$x(\theta,z)=zcos(\theta)$

$y(\theta,z)=zsin(\theta)$

$z=z$

for $\theta \in [0,2\pi]$ and $z \in [0,2]$

The 2-differential form will get it last termcanceled as

$\mathrm{d}\theta \wedge \mathrm{d}\theta =0$

And the first two term will give me

$[z^4cos^2(\theta) sin(\theta)+z^3sin^2(\theta)cos(\theta)] \mathrm{d}\theta \,\wedge \mathrm{d}z$

Issue with this is that integral of either trigonometric terms will be $0$ over $[0,2\pi]$

So I am curious if I am correct or there is something wrong in my computation/approach, any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can use \wedge instead of \Lambda

Comment: @NinadMunshi Thanks I edited it

Comment: Why exactly does the last term vanish? Are you sure that you computed the pullbacks of $dx$ and $dy$ correctly?

Comment: @amd what pullbacks did you get? I got $\mathrm{d}x=-z\, sin(\theta) \mathrm{d}\theta$ and $\mathrm{d}y=z\, cos(\theta)\mathrm{d}\theta$, or is it more complicated?

Comment: You’ve made both $x$ and $y$ functions of $z$, so $dx = -z\sin\theta\,d\theta+\cos\theta\,dz$ and $dy = z\cos\theta\,d\theta+\sin\theta\,dz$. It might be less confusing if you don’t reuse the name $z$ for the new variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both $x$ and $y$ are dependent on $z$, so their pullbacks ought to include a $dz$ term. I think that you might have confused yourself by using the name ‘$z$’ for two different things. Let’s call the new variable $v$ instead so that we have $(\theta,v)\mapsto(v\cos\theta,v\sin\theta,v)$. Then clearly $dx = -v\sin\theta\,d\theta + \cos\theta\,dv$, $dy = v\cos\theta\,d\theta+\sin\theta\,dv$ and $dx\wedge dy = -v\,d\theta\wedge dv \ne 0$. The integral of that term over $\theta\in[0,2\pi]$ won’t vanish.